# use of stringstream as default value inside an inline function

Tags: c++, cout, stringstream

i'm on c++03 and i've just begin to approach c++.

i want to to make a function that set some properties on a string stream and return it (or mayebe passing it by reference)

```
inline stringstream get_fixed_stream(stringstream ss=stringstream("")) {
    ss.precision(4);
    ss.setf(ios::fixed);
    return ss;
}
```

so if i call:

```
stringstream ss = get_fixed_stream()
```

i recive a new strinstring, if i call

cout = get_fixed_stream(cout)

the precision and setf are settet to cout.

i get this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/streambuf:770: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is private
/usr/include/c++/4.4/iosfwd:63: error: within this context
```

Comment: You're trying to return a stream by value. This won't work, streams are non-copyable. It's what error message is telling you: the stream class' copy-constructor is private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cout` is not a stringstream and can't be passed in as one.

try this instead

```
template<typename Stream>
void fix_stream(Stream& stream){ 
    stream.precision(4);
    stream.setf(std::ios::fixed);
}
:::
fix_stream(std::cout);
std::stringstream ss;
fix_stream(ss);
```

Comment: +1, I like this approach since it works (at least) for all std::ios_base types.

Comment: @AlexP. it is a bit of a mallet for a mole hill, I am sure capturing the ostream base would every bit as good in most cases, but this will work with anything that compiles with that interface.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a reference (the *&* below):

```
inline stringstream & get_fixed_stream(stringstream & ss)
{
ss.precision(4);
ss.setf(ios::fixed);
return ss;
}
```